# Como retornar uma valor inteiro referente as rows no codeiginter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como faço para retornar uma valor inteiro referente as linhas retornadas no select?

```
$query = $this->db->where("categoria_titulo", $categoria);
$query = $this->db->get("categorias");
$query = $query->num_rows();
echo $query;
```

Comment: Postei uma resposta, tente daquela forma, qualquer coisa me avise... Uso bastante codeigniter. Se quiser me adicionar no skype para trocarmos algumas figurinhas, anote: srandrebaill - ATt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina uma variavel para a pesquisa de numero de registros:

```
                $query = $this->db->where("categoria_titulo", $categoria);
                $query = $this->db->get("categorias");
                $query_num = $query->num_rows();
                echo $query_num;
```

Ou então faça

```
                $query = $this->db->where("categoria_titulo", $categoria);
                $query = $this->db->get("categorias");
                return $query->num_rows();
```